# Are bolt and nut dimensions standardized?

Tags: cad, fasteners, standards, bolting

Given the nominal size of a bolt/nut, e.g M10, can one construct all other dimensions from it? Do these dimensions differ between manufacturers or are these standardized. If so, where can I find tables with these dimensions. My goal is to make a CAD design library with all these DIN/ISO bolts. For this I need all exact dimensions.

Comment: Yes, metric, Whitworth, UNC etc etc all the details are easily found.

Comment: Inventor already has such a CAD design library. You can also download bolt CAD files from McMaster.

Comment: The bolt&nut dimensions are standardised, just be sure to pick the right [standard](https://boltport.com/technical/bolts-dimension-standards/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thread shape and pitch of all M-series nuts & bolts is standardised.  So an M10 nut from one manufacturer will fit an M10 bolt from another.

There's no standard for the length - you can buy bolts in a wide variety of different lengths.

There are lots of different head styles too, but if you're thinking of a hexagonal nut and hex-head bolt, then it should be the same wherever you buy it.  Find the web supplier of a reputable company that provides data sheets.

Answer (score 0):

I remember in high school drawing these by hand. The basic design is an hexagonal head chamfered at 45° to the diameter of the inscribed circle to the points of the hexagon.

M10 means 1mm across the flats or specifically the diameter of the inscribed circle.

An M32 would have a 32mm diameter circle.

The height of the head is proportional to the diameter at 50%. So an M10 is over designed compared to an M32 due to material strength properties and tools used.